# search in notepad++ with wildcard

Tags: notepad++, wildcard

this is my doccument:

```
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{66899421-F497-4503-8C9D-ADAE290F2F27}\ProxyStubClsid32]
    @="{E6D78900-BB40-4039-9C54-593A242B65DA}"
Das= 66999930-6E32-4506-A362-733C16E4DBF9
```

how can i search all the value like : ........-....-....-....-............ (GUID) , not in the key name.
with this example, how can i get :

```
E6D78900-BB40-4039-9C54-593A242B65DA
66999930-6E32-4506-A362-733C16E4DBF9
```

Thanks so much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with:

Find what: `(?<!\\\{)[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}`